# Is $d$ a metric for $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^2 $  define $d(x,y)$ = smallest integer greater or equal to usual
distance between $x$ and $y$. Is $d$ a metric for $\mathbb{R}^2?$

My attempt : I think No, take $x=[0.1] , y=[0.2]$ then $d(x,y)=0$ but $x\neq  y$

Is its correct ?

Comment: Yes of course !!

Comment: thanks u @EDX...

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: @jasmine: It’s true that $d$ is not a metric, but your example does not work, because it’s in $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb R^2$. Use the points $\langle 0.1,0\rangle$ and $\langle 0.2,0\rangle$, however, and it will work fine.

Comment: @EDX: Not quite: the example is in the wrong space, though it can easily be modified to work in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: The usual distance between $(0.1,0)$ and $(0.2,0)$ is $0.1.$ So $d((0.1,0),(0.2,0))=1$ because $1$ is the smallest integer $ \ge 0.1.$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes thanks for your precision

Comment: It is the composition of the Euclidean metric with the ceiling function (not the floor function).

Comment: Right. Suppose $(X,\rho)$ is a metric space. Then $\lceil \cdot \rceil \circ \rho$ IS a metric but $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor \circ \rho$ is NOT a metric (it is a pseudometric).

Comment: Matt is right. As the question is formulated, "smallest integer greater or equal to usual distance" is the ceiling function, not floor. $\lceil 0.1\rceil$ is $1$, not $0$. With the ceiling function, $d$ happens to be a metric

Comment: I should add that there are special cases where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor \circ \rho$ is a metric such as the discrete metric. Also I was not being too careful when I said it would be a pseudometric as there are pretty obvious examples of where the triangle inequality is violated as well. For example:  $\lfloor |1-0| \rfloor=1$ but $\lfloor |1-1/2| \rfloor+\lfloor |1/2-0| \rfloor=0+0=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $d(x,y)=\lceil d_2(x,y)\rceil$ where $d_2(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$ is a metric. Indeed, $d$ is a metric if we change $d_2$ for any metric on $\mathbb{R}^2.$

- $d(x,x)\ge 0?$

Yes, since $d(x,y)=\lceil d_2(x,x) \rceil \ge \lceil 0 \rceil \ge 0.$

- $d(x,x)=0 \iff x=y?$

Yes: $x=y\iff d_2(x,y)=0 \iff \lceil d_2(x,y)\rceil=0\iff d(x,y)=0.$

- $d(x,y)=d(y,x)?$

Yes, because $d(x,y)=\lceil d_2(x,y) \rceil=\lceil d_2(y,x) \rceil=d(y,x).$

- $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(y,z)?$

Yes: $d(x,y)=\lceil d_2(x,y) \rceil\le \lceil d_2(x,z)+d_2(y,z) \rceil \le \lceil d_2(x,z)\rceil + \lceil d_2(y,z) \rceil=d(x,z)+d(y,z).$